# how to use variables from one function in another function

Tags: c++

Working on a little terminal gpa calculator program in c++ and I am struggling to call a set of variables I defined in one function via user input to another function. Here is the code. The usergrades function is my function to get all number grades from the user. I would like to use those variables in function gpacalculation to add them together and write the gpa calculation formula using those variables to spit out the gpa. Could someone explain how to call those variables for use in another function.

```
int usergrades()
{
    int grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5;
    
    cout << "list out all your grades?" << endl;
    cout << "grade 1:";
    cin >> grade1;
    cout << "grade 2:";
    cin >> grade2;
    cout << "grade 3:";
    cin >> grade3;
    cout << "grade 4:";
    cin >> grade4;
    cout << "grade 5:";
    cin >> grade5;
    
    return grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5;
}

void gpacalculation()
{
    
    
    
}

int main()
{
    
    
    usergrades();
    gpacalculation();
    
    return 0;
  
}
```

Do I need to use them as parameters in the usergrades function and remove the variable from it and then call those parameters in the gpacalculation function in main? I have tried variations of that and always get the "not defined in this scope" error.

Comment: `return` returns ONE variable. Period. You can build many variables into one container and return the container, for example see Structured Bindings in your C++ text, but Highlander's Law is still in full effect: There Can Be Only One.

Comment: std::vector<int> grade. Pass it as a reference parameter.

Comment: Another way is to open your C++ textbook to the chapter that introduces and explains C++ classes, how they work, how to use them, and what class methods are, how they work, and how to use them, and how class methods share class members as common variables, of sorts. This is exactly what classes are for.

Comment: `int usergrades()` means the function promises it will return exactly 1 value. Also the comma operator does not do what you think.

Comment: It seems I may have gotten ahead of myself with the mention of vectors and OOP. I also did not know you could only return 1 value period.  That part didn't throw an error so I assumed it was fine. Thanks everyone so far for the input. I'm only a couple weeks in to the reading, my class hasn't even started yet Just trying to get ahead with a foundation.

Comment: What allowed the code you tried to compile is the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). Everything on the left side of the comma is evaluated and the result is discarded. Then the right side is evaluated and the result is passed on, in this case to the next comma. So what `return grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5;` really does is `return grade5;` because the other expressions in the statement have no side-effects.

Comment: [Simple example using `vector`](https://godbolt.org/z/x85PrhbEh), but Sam's right. For this stage of your programming course you're probably better off building a `Student` class that collects, calculates and displays the grades.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to pass variables between functions.

So the first thing to notice is that when you call a function, you may want to put variables IN or you may want to take variables OUT.
Then there is a mix, which are variables which you want to put INto the function, but you also want get the changed variable OUT.

IN variables: variables you want to put into a function but don't want changed.

- we usually pass to a function "by copy"

```
void do_something(int variable)
{
    /*use the variable*/
}
```

OUT variables: the function doesn't care about the variables initial value, it just overwrites it.

there are 2 ways:

- get it returned

```
int calculate_something()
{
    int variable = 0;
    /*calculate the variable*/
    return variable;
}

void use_calculate_something()
{
    int my_variable;

    my_variable = calculate_something();

    /* my_variable now has the calculated value */
}
```

- pass in a variable "by reference", which will be modified

```
void calculate_something(int& variable)
{
    variable = /* calculate the variable */;
}

void use_calculate_something()
{
    int my_variable;

    calculate_something(my_variable);

    /* my_variable now has the calculated value */
}
```

IN/OUT variables: the function uses the initial value of the variable, and it also overwrites it.

- this is the same passing in a variable "by reference" (above).

In the function definition the varaibles have a special name: parameters:

- `void do_something(int parameter)`
- `void caculate_something(int& parameter)`